# Create Struct from a String?

Tags: ruby, struct

I need to create a Struct with multiple fields (based on a long string).
Here is what I have so far:

```
s = "a1|b2|c3|"
a = s.split("|")
b = []
a.each { |e| 
  b.push(e.to_sym)
}

Str = Struct.new(*b)
```

Anyway to make it shorter?

Comment: Whenever it's a question about "how do I improve this", that's a flag that the question probably belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `b = []; a.each {|e| b << (do something with e) }` can always be shortened to a use of `map`. So:

```
s = "a1|b2|c3"
b = s.split('|').map {|e| e.to_sym }
```

Or, even more tersely:

```
s = "a1|b2|c3"
b = s.split('|').map(&:to_sym)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here it is:

```
Str = Struct.new(*"a1|b2|c3|".split("|").map(&:to_sym))
```